# Why is Bitmap loading still so slow even with Google's implementation?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, bitmap, imageview

I use these two functions, slightly modified from Google's code in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to use filepaths:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFilePath(String pathName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
}
```

With the idea being to use a scaled-down version of the Bitmap to be mapped onto an ImageView rather than the full-thing, which is wasteful.

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFilePath(pathToFile, 100, 100));
```

I implemented a thing where you press a button and it rotates to the next image, but there's still a significant lag (it takes a moment for the ImageView to populate) on my phone compared to my emulator. And then occasionally my phone app will crash and I can't replicate it on my emulator.

Is there a problem with this code I've posted above? Is there a problem with the way I am using the code?

Example:

```
public void reloadPic() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromFilePath(filepath, mImageViewWidth, mImageViewHeight);
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is jumping between threads several times.  First you launch a thread.  Then you wait for it to be scheduled  You decode on that thread.  Then you post a command to the UI thread and wait for it to be scheduled.  THen you post a draw command to the ui thread (that's part of what setImageBitmap does).  Then you have to process any other commands that came in first.  Then you actually draw the screen.  There's really only 3 ways to speed this up:

1) Get rid of the thread.  You shouldn't decode lots of images on the UI thread, but decoding 1 isn't too bad.

2)Store the images in the right size to begin with.  This may mean creating thumbnails of the images ahead of time.  Then you don't need to scale.

3)Preload your images.  If there's only one button and you know what image it will load, load it before you need it, so when the button is pressed you have it ready.  Wastes a bit of memory, but only 1 image worth.  (This isn't a viable solution if you have a lot of possible next images).

Comment: I thought it was just a straightforward "do the bitmap stuff on another thread, then go back to the UI thread to map to ImageView." Is this not the standard way to do such things?

Comment: YOu're right on what you're doing.  My description is how doing that actually has to be implemented behind the scenes.  Your code is the standard way of scaling a bitmap, but for one image there really isn't a reason to pass it to another thread-  you need to use another thread when you're decoding a bunch of images.  Decoding one isn't all that bad.

Comment: In my use case, there are potentially many images (but only one is viewable at a time), and the user may wish to share the full-size version. To me this suggests options 2 and 3 use a lot of extra memory, right? Do you think option 1 is my best bet?

Comment: 2 would be storing it on disk as thumbnails.  So it would be more a storage issue than memory, making it not too bad.  3 isn't probably a good idea if there's many images, although 3 with a cache could be viable if your usecase includes a lot of displaying of the same images over again.

Comment: There are potentially hundreds of images, so preloading them all into immediate memory may be an issue. But if I did options 1 and 2, that would be the best of both worlds? Lots of tiny images that don't require extra decoding, plus no thread-jumping, with minimal impact on the UI thread?

Comment: On the plus side, removing the thread definitely fixed the crashing issue for whatever reason. It's still a bit slow so I'll try option 2 on top of this. Thanks!